# Why is my iOS 6 device missing all iTunes Match playlists?

Tags: itunes-match, ios

After upgrading to iOS I don't see any iCloud playing list in my iPhone.

The lists are OK in iTunes on my two OS X devices but not on the iPhone.

In the *Music* settings:

- *iTunes Match* is switched on
- *show all music* is also switched on

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling and enabling *iTunes Match* several times solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer, be sure to select it so that others can see it above the other alternate answers.

Answer (score 2):

I also found renaming the missing playlist in OS X caused it to appear back on a device that wasn't showing it.